# New to Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I'm new to Netsuite world but need to do some administration at my current job. Here are my questions related to Netsuite.

1. Where can I create a Developer Account/signup for Netsuite so that I can login and  learn some configuration.
2. Any online resources to learn configuration/administration or I need to take the actual training?
3. What are the programming languages we need to know for development and what is the scope of customization in Netsuite?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic here.

Answer (score 7):

1) [Here](https://forms.netsuite.com/app/site/crm/externalcustrecordpage.nl?compid=NLCORP&formid=1011&h=b60879b7abbdb19d909e&ck=AAAAAEADAjsyYsKI&vid=c3BtuvkCAqMg_823&cktime=131882&redirect_count=1&did_javascript_redirect=T) is the link for Developer Account/Signup for Netsuite.

They usually take some time to process your Dev account request, once they verify your details, you'll get a response mail from Netsuite with a given link to access it with a temporary password.

2) Truely speaking, you have to grab everything on your own efforts.There is no decent and pretty formatted way to get everything from one particular place(unless you ready to pay for some heavy amount for the webinars).

Once you get the login access in to Netsuite (Dev account) you can explore the help documents for more details.
Next thing in the series and which is very obvious is to join [Netsuite User Forum](https://usergroup.netsuite.com/users/index.php?). Once you became a member, you can post queries and discover a lot of new ideas about how industry is using Netsuite in different fields.

3) Netsuite provides supports for Java, .NET & PHP (SOAP based access).
Apart from that Netsuite does also provide a REST based access through RESTlets which is an extension of server side javascript.